# Firestore onSnapshot -> Does it work for subcollections?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is the method onSnapshot of firestore triggered by any changes in subcollections?

What is the difference between

```js
db.firestore.collection('x').onSnapshot
```

And

```js
db.firestore.collection('x').doc('y').collection('z').onSnapshot
```

Are they equal????

Answer (score 17):

A change to a subcollection organized under a document do not count as changes to the document itself.  They will not trigger a snapshot event on that document.

Listening to a subcollection is not any different than listening to a top-level collection.  In both cases, the listener will only be triggered by changes to documents within that collection or subcollection.