# Firestore Cloud Function listen to subcollection but not parent collection

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

This is copied from the documentation of Firebase:-
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions

The comment said the listener will listen all documents in the 'users' AND all subcollections.

How can I just listen to all documents of subcollections but not the parent collection? (i.e. DO NOT listen to documents in 'users' in this example.)

```
// Listen for changes in all documents in the 'users' collection and all subcollections
exports.useMultipleWildcards = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}/{messageCollectionId}/{messageId}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
      // If we set `/users/marie/incoming_messages/134` to {body: "Hello"} then
      // context.params.userId == "marie";
      // context.params.messageCollectionId == "incoming_messages";
      // context.params.messageId == "134";
      // ... and ...
      // change.after.data() == {body: "Hello"}
    });index.js
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation [Specify a group of documents using wildcards](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions#wildcards-parameters):

> If you want to attach a trigger to a group of documents, such as any document in a certain collection, then use a {wildcard} in place of the document ID

Additionally, I searched here a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52309507/firestore-onsnapshot-does-it-work-for-subcollections):

> A change to a subcollection organized under a document do not count as changes to the document itself. They will not trigger a snapshot event on that document.

> Listening to a subcollection is not any different than listening to a top-level collection. In both cases, the listener will only be triggered by changes to documents within that collection or subcollection.

Then I can conclude that this is not possible.