# Listen to changes of a doc and its sub collections in firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to run a function when a doc in parent collection or a doc in a sub collections changes, I used the code below mentioned in the firebase documentations but it only triggers when a doc is changed in sub collections and it does not trigger when a doc in the parent collection changes

```
// Listen for changes in all documents in the 'users' collection and all subcollections
exports.useMultipleWildcards = functions.firestore
.document('users/{userId}/{messageCollectionId}/{messageId}')
.onWrite((change, context) => {
});
```

my code:

```
export const generateAllBooks = functions.firestore
  .document('books/{bookId}/{variantsCollectionId}/{variantId}')
  .onWrite(async (_change, _context) => {});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the firebase docs and  [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52317367/20239914) posted by **Doug Stevenson**

> A change to a subcollection organized under a document does not count as changes to the document itself. They will not trigger a snapshot event on that document.

And

> Listening to a subcollection is not any different than listening to a top-level collection. In both cases, the listener will only be triggered by changes to documents within that collection or subcollection.

So TLDR, to trigger the firebase function on both parent and its subcollection you will need to deploy 2 separate functions. Although you can make them call one common method to execute the same.

Example :

```
export const triggetForParent = functions.firestore
  .document('books/{bookId}')
  .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
    functions.logger.log("After Changed data : ", change.after.data());
    // Code to run when a document in the 'books' collection at top level gets changed
    await commonMethod(change, context);
  });

export const triggerForSubCollections = functions.firestore
  .document('books/{bookId}/{variantsCollectionId}/{variantId}')
  .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
    functions.logger.log("After Changed data : ", change.after.data());
    // Code to run when a document in the subcollection is changed
    await commonMethod(change, context);
  });

async function commonMethod(change, context) {
  // This method can be shared between both functions
}
```

Reference : [**Writing Cloud Firestore-triggered functions**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#event_triggers)

Comment: yes I just did like this, thanks